# Infinite loop in Key Value Observing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, key-value-observing

Everytime i run the code it run in infinite loop and call the function `myProperty` over and over again. What should i do to overcome this..I have written the following code in viewDidLoad function of the viewController.

`[self.model addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myProperty" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];`

`[self.model myProperty];`

here i have a `Model` class and it has a property named `myProperty` and a method or a getter `myProperty`.I am using`myProperty` to connect to a database a collect all the values of a column and store it in `myProperty`. I have checked `myProperty` method..it is doing fine **without KVO**. But when i add this KVO this goes into infinite loop.

again i have also used

`- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath` 
`ofObject:(id)object` 
                        `change:(NSDictionary *)change 
                       context:(void *)context
{`

`if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"myProperty"])`
        
        `NSLog(@"called");`

`}`

and my `myProperty` method is

`- (void) myProperty`
{

```
NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyDatabase" ofType:@"db"];

    sqlite3 *database = NULL;


sqlite3_stmt *stmt;



NSMutableArray *availableNames=[NSMutableArray array];


if (sqlite3_open([file UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
{


    NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from Names"];


    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &stmt, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
    {


        while (sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_ROW) {




            [availableNames addObject:[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt,1 )]];
        }


        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

        }

}
sqlite3_close(database);

self.myProperty = availableNames;


}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: what is self.model data type??? is NSArray? Is there a more detailed code? could you post Infinite loop code?

Comment: self.model is a object of my `Model` class and also a property of the viewController. ok, nevermind, i am editing the question..

Comment: When you post the most detailed you can get a great answer.

Comment: You need to post your `getMyProperty` method.

Comment: @bitmapdata.com--i have updated..please check..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, rename `getMyProperty` to simply `myProperty`.  Methods should not be prefixed with `get`.

Secondly, you need to post the implementation of `getMyProperty` and post part of the backtrace of the infinite loop.   Most likely, your getter is triggering a mutation which is triggering KVO which triggers the getter which triggers the mutation which triggers KVO....

---

```
self.myProperty = availableNames;
```

That's your problem right there;  you are changing state from your getter which leads to the infinite loop described above.   Getters really shouldn't be that complex;  do you really want to open a database connection and read from disk every single time you ask for the available names?   Slow!

Split that out;  create a `loadAvailableNames` method that can be called at an appropriate time (`if (self.needsLoading) [self loadAavailableNames]; return _myProperty;`, etc...).

Also -- writing against the raw SQLite API is both a waste of time and really hard to get right.  If you need portability of database, use something like FMDB.   If you want to maximally leverage system capabilities, use Core Data.